# How to plot varius plots in different figures from different variables of a dataframe with minimum code ggplot2/R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wonder if there is a function in `ggplot2` package or another package or a for-loop way in `R` to create different figures of plots from various variables/columns of a dataframe without coding every one, each figure for each variable. For example, if I have a dataframe called df with several columns: `id` (keys of data), `v1`, `v2`, ..., `v10`. I would like to plot various variables (`v2` to `v8`) in axis Y, with `v1` in axis X, but not repeating the same code for every single variable.

```r
# For 1 plot, how could I code for various plots?    
plot_v2 <- df %>% # (plot_name as column name, i.e plot_v2)
  ggplot( aes(x=v1, y=v2, group=id, color=id)) +
    geom_line()
```

This code creates a figure with a plot, I want to know a way to do this for all variables `v2` to `v8` in axis Y, with a new figure for each one.

This is just a theorical question, any suggestion or hint about a function to look or a way to write the for-loop will be very helful. I can't provide any sample data. I tried once using a for loop but there are some issues when I have to specify the name of the variable for the axis in `aes()` as well as the name of the plot object. Really appreciate any help!

Because my first post asking this doubt happened to be closed, I'll make it clear, I don't want to plot all the variables in the same plot/figure, I want to know how to create a new figure for every variable. Something like in Matlab it would be using figure() function every time and iterating over the columns of a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define an example dataframe

```r
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = runif(40, min = 0, max = 20), 
  v2 = runif(40, min = -10, max = 10),
  v3 = runif(40, min = -30, max = 40),
  v4 = runif(40, min = -30, max = 40),
  v5 = runif(40, min = -30, max = 40),
  v6 = runif(40, min = -30, max = 40),
  v7 = runif(40, min = -30, max = 40),
  v8 = runif(40, min = -30, max = 40),
  id = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), each = 10)
)
```

We can define a function that takes an index and the dataframe as input and generates a plot based on the index passed

```r
# to change the selected columns, edit `[[i + 1]]`
make_plot <- function(i, df) {
  df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = v1, y = .[[i + 1]], color = id)) +
    geom_line()
}
```

Finally we represent the plots by invoking the lapply function

```r
lapply(1:7, make_plot, df)
```

Comment: This solution was what I needed! Do you know a way to plot individually for every id? So I can plot values for  v2 for 'a', v2 for 'b',... in individual figures. I tried with a for and filter():

  for (m in unique(df$id)){
    df %>%
      filter(id == m) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = v1, y = .[[i + 1]], color = id)) +
      geom_line() +
      labs(y = colnames(df)[i+1])
  } 
But the output is 'NULL'

Comment: I would appreciate to know if there is a way to store every plot/figure in a list as well. Thanks!

Comment: you can assign the result of `lapply` to a variable (e.g. `list_plot`) and get single plots with `list_plot[[i]]`. Please, if the answer was helpful to you, please consider upvote and accept it