# Boxploting many variables over different pages

Tags: r, ggplot2, bigdata, boxplot

### Boxplotting a big data set (in one run)

How can I pass from a code that throws 280 boxplots at once, to a code that separates each variable, and gets me 280 different plots?

*All the examples that I have found contain less than 5 variables,* making the output easy to handle and to recognize ... but how do you do it with more than 15 variables to plot?

I have a big data set (long format= 77560 observation, 3 variables; wide format= 280 observations, 278 variables). This data set contains clinical data and measurements from 2 groups, patients and controls.

My goal is to boxplot controls against patients, from all the 280 variables, and get the result in different plots (different outcome windows).

I would like to have one code, instead of doing this 280 times.

How can I get the 280 boxplots in a more reasonable output?

Thanks!

**The code that I am using is this:**

```
ggplot(long_df, aes(x=variable, y=value)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=group))
```

**This is how 4 rows from 15 columns look like:**

```
    df <- structure(list(group = c("control", "control", "patient", 
"patient"), `Scale factor` = c(0.80696, 0.8002, 0.73286, 0.83765
), SNR = c(19.1027, 17.8508, 19.2552, 15.002), mSNR = c(20.2588, 
18.9367, 20.1892, 16.1166), `ICV cm3` = c(1461.351, 1426.9219, 
1350.5229, 1565.7709), `Cerebellum total cm3` = c(128.4798, 125.1114, 
124.4808, 143.9827), `Cerebellum right cm3` = c(64.2286, 62.7666, 
62.0081, 71.7966), `Cerebellum left cm3` = c(64.2512, 62.3449, 
62.4727, 72.1861), `Cerebellum total %` = c(8.7919, 8.7679, 9.2172, 
9.1956), `Cerebellum right %` = c(4.3952, 4.3987, 4.5914, 4.5854
), `Cerebellum left %` = c(4.3967, 4.3692, 4.6258, 4.6103), `Cerebellum asymmetry` = c(-0.035173, 
0.67412, -0.74651, -0.54105), `I-II total cm3` = c(0.11782, 0.10723, 
0.090875, 0.13486), `I-II right cm3` = c(0.058101, 0.056814, 
0.043239, 0.069525), `I-II left cm3` = c(0.059715, 0.050412, 
0.047636, 0.065337)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**wide to long:**

```
long_df <- melt(df, id.var="group")
```

**how can I pass from this**
[image]

**... to 280 *regular* boxplots like this one ...**
[image]

Comment: Do you think you will be able to see something in a plot of 280 boxplots?

Comment: No. that's the thing. I don't want 280 boxplots in one single window, I need them to be in separate windows. That is the result that I have so far, which is exactly what I am trying to change... 
I will make that clearer in my question. thanks for bringing that up

Comment: Ok. You will find the solution in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69738268/how-to-plot-varius-plots-in-different-figures-from-different-variables-of-a-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### LOOPING TROUGH facet_wrap_paginate() WITH A FOR LOOP

(also, other facet facet_wrap_ options may serve)

Note, the data frame must be in a long version (long_df)

```
## THE BOXPLOT
############
for(i in 1:n) {  # n= the total number of pages
  plots <- long_df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(group, value))+
    geom_boxplot(aes(color = group)) +
    geom_jitter( width = 0.10)+
    stat_compare_means(method = "t.test", paired = FALSE) + #adding a t-test
    facet_wrap_paginate(~ variable, ncol = 3, nrow = 2, page = i, scales='free')
    print(plots)
}

## FINISH ##
```

**Outcome example:**

[image: RESULT EXAMPLE]

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use data Standardization. Meaning that you recalculate the values into values between -1 and 1, but keep the relative diferences.

```
df <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(-group), ~(scale(.) %>% as.vector))
long_df <- data.table::melt(df, id.var="group")
ggplot(long_df, aes(x=variable, y=value)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=group)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

Comment: I should notice that there are several different methods to recalculate values. The one I use is just one of them and you should check which is the most suitable for your study and/or your scientific field. And finally, I have never seen a plot showing so many different variables (I mean 280). Maybe you should reconsider and group variables by some scientific logic.

Comment: that is a good code @Bloxx , unfortunately is not what I am looking for. I edited my question to make it more clear. I would like to get the outcome in different "windows", as if I was plotting one by one  :)